# Convert array of colors to array of floats

Tags: arrays, colors, julia

I have an array of colors, which I want to convert to a matrix of numbers:

```
using Colors

cols = [RGB{Float64}(rand(), rand(), rand()) for i in 1:6]
6-element Array{ColorTypes.RGB{Float64},1}:
RGB{Float64}(0.836012,0.505908,0.249548)
RGB{Float64}(0.383172,0.105153,0.361422)
RGB{Float64}(0.680616,0.974232,0.942787)
RGB{Float64}(0.804829,0.825503,0.990222)
RGB{Float64}(0.0404051,0.569093,0.772053)
RGB{Float64}(0.872298,0.704112,0.473588)
```

converted to:

```
6×3 Array{Float64,2}:
0.836012  0.505908  0.249548
0.383172  0.105153  0.361422
0.680616  0.974232  0.942787
0.804829  0.825503  0.990222
0.0404051 0.569093 0.772053
0.872298  0.704112  0.473588
```

How would I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `reinterpret`.  It "constructs an array with the same binary data as the given array, but with the specified element type."  That means that it reads the data in the same order — and remember that Julia is column major.  It also doesn't know what shape the returned array should be, so by default it's just a vector:

```
julia> reinterpret(Float64, cols)
18-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.836012
 0.505908
 0.249548
 0.383172
 0.105153
 ⋮
```

You can see that it's pulled out the floating point values and placed them all in a flat vector `[c₁,c₂]` becomes `[r₁, g₁, b₁, r₂, g₂, b₂]`.  So you want to first get a 3x6 array that respects this structure:

```
julia> fs = reinterpret(Float64, cols, (3, length(cols)))
3x6 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.836012  0.383172  0.680616  0.804829  0.0404051  0.872298
 0.505908  0.105153  0.974232  0.825503  0.569093   0.704112
 0.249548  0.361422  0.942787  0.990222  0.772053   0.473588
```

Now you can get to the shape you want by taking the transpose if you need it:

```
julia> fs'
6x3 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.836012   0.505908  0.249548
 0.383172   0.105153  0.361422
 0.680616   0.974232  0.942787
 0.804829   0.825503  0.990222
 0.0404051  0.569093  0.772053
 0.872298   0.704112  0.473588
```

Comment: Thanks! I always wondered what `reinterpret` did — it looks very useful!

Comment: Yup, it does its thing without copying the data at all, so it'll be the fastest possible way to do it!  Watch out, though, since this means that modifying the reinterpreted array will also affect your array of `RGB`s.

Answer (score 1):

One way is:

```
[j(cols[i]) for i=1:6,j in [red,green,blue]]
```

Comment: `vcat(map(x->[red(x) green(x) blue(x)],cols)...)` is same flavor, but is better for type-analysis. Benchmarking shows it is faster than the answer. But probably @Matt B.'s option is even faster.

Comment: Thanks—I don't know why I didn't get there... :) As you say, the `reinterpret` is much quicker.

Comment: @DanGetz is `cat(n, map(f,x)...)` a "Julian" or at least a good way of achieving something like this generally? I often use it but am never sure whether there is a better way?